# ArcGis Workstation with 10.3 license

Tags: arcgis-10.3, arcinfo-workstation

Can I install Workstation 9.3 with ArcGis 10.3 and use the same (individual) license? If i can, anything to look out for?

Comment: That sounds like a better question for ESRI support.

Comment: 9.3 Workstation has been retired for a long time now. It **cannot** use more modern licenses; in fact, I believe the license managers are incompatible.  Even the 10.0 Workstation is retired, so the ability to license *any* Workstation is unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

No, each license is version-specific. You can use a 10.3 with a 10.2 and 10.1 ArcGIS, but not 10.0 and below (or 10.4 and above). The following License Administrator has both licenses for 10.1-10.3 and licenses for 10.0, they are separate products:

[image: ArcGIS multi-license Server Administrator]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get a response on here, it might be worth asking on GeoNet about this. I just read over various details there about getting Workstation working with newer ArcGIS versions. e.g https://community.esri.com/message/620821